# How can I play a .ts in Exoplayer 2

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I started using `ExoPlayer` recently to play stream links on my android application, such as `.m3u8` and `.mp4` files, but when I tried to play `.ts` files, the message below started appearing in the Android logcat:

> Source error.
> com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException:
> Input does not start with the #EXTM3U header.
> at
> com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.playlist.HlsPlaylistParser.parse(HlsPlaylistParser.java:119)
> at
> com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.playlist.HlsPlaylistParser.parse(HlsPlaylistParser.java:43)
> at
> com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.ParsingLoadable.load(ParsingLoadable.java:115)
> at
> com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:315)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

Is there a possibility to play `.ts` streams with `EXOPlayer2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a supported format. Check here https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/supported-formats.html

Answer (score 1):

MPEG-TS ist supported.
hier in there FAQ https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/faqs.html
are telling that you have to use the Flags FLAG_ALLOW_NON_IDR_KEYFRAMES and FLAG_DETECT_ACCESS_UNITS to make it works. but right now i don't know how .